# Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm learning laravel4 with tutorials step by step ,
I used that code many times but it's the first time it gives me this error, that's my controller part of code

```
public function getIndex () {
    $categories = array();


    foreach ( Category::all() as $key=> $category) {
        $categories[$category->id] = $category->name ;
    }


    return View::make('products.index')
    ->with('products' , Product::all())
    ->with('categories' , $categories);
 }
```

and this is the view part of code

```
<ul>    @if(is_array($products))

    @foreach ($products as $product)
        <li>
            {{HTML::image($product->image , $product->title , array('width'=>'50'))  }}
            {{ $product->title }} - 
            {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'admin/products/destroy')) }}
            {{ Form::hidden ('id' , $product->id) }}
            {{ Form::submit('delete') }}
            {{ Form::close() }}


            {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'admin/products/toggle-availability'))}}
            {{ Form::hidden ('id', $product->id)}}
            {{ Form::select('availability' , array('1'=>'In stock' , '0'=>'out of stock') , $product->availability) }}
            {{ Form::submit ('update') }}
            {{ Form:: close() }}
        </li>
@endforeach 
    @endif
```

adding

`dd(Product::all());` in the controller .. thats what i get

```
>     object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#170 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(Product)#168 (20) {
> ["fillable":protected]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(11) "category_id"
> [1]=> string(5) "title" [2]=> string(11) "description" [3]=> string(5)
> "price" [4]=> string(12) "availability" [5]=> string(5) "image" }
> ["connection":protected]=> NULL ["table":protected]=> NULL
> ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["perPage":protected]=>
> int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["timestamps"]=> bool(true)
> ["attributes":protected]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> int(0)
> ["category_id"]=> int(1) ["title"]=> string(4) "test"
> ["description"]=> string(4) "test" ["price"]=> string(2) "22"
> ["availability"]=> int(0) ["image"]=> string(0) "" ["updated_at"]=>
> string(10) "0000-00-00" ["created_at"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" }
> ["original":protected]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> int(0) ["category_id"]=>
> int(1) ["title"]=> string(4) "test" ["description"]=> string(4) "test"
> ["price"]=> string(2) "22" ["availability"]=> int(0) ["image"]=>
> string(0) "" ["updated_at"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" ["created_at"]=>
> string(10) "0000-00-00" } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { }
> ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) {
> } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=>
> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { }
> ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=>
> array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0) { }
> ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL ["exists"]=> bool(true) } } }
```

Comment: Either `Category::all()` or `Product::all()` is returning null.  Find which one it is, trace the code backwards through the respective function, or perhaps that will highlight the issue for you.

Comment: Is the error showing that the problem is in the blade template, or in the controller?

Comment: 1 `is_array($products)` is always false, because it's a `Collection` not an array. 2 There is no piece in code you pasted, that would throw the error, you talk about - both `Product::all()` and `Category::all()` return a `Collection` which, even empty, can be provided to `foreach`. Check again that error, it will tell you where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
return View::make('products.index')
->with('products' , Product::all())
->with('categories' , $categories);
```

To

```
$product = new Product;
$products = $product->get();

return View::make('products.index'), array(
  'products' => $products,
  'categories' => $categories
);
```

Comment: do u mean `
return View::make('products.index')->with( array(
  'products' => $products,
  'categories' => $categories
));` ?

Comment: Nope, you can pass variables into a view using an array like that. Check out the laravel docs. http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#basic-controllers

Comment: It doesn't change anything